# What's the largest value an NSNumber can store?

Tags: objective-c, max, nsnumber, primitive

What's the largest value an NSNumber can store?

```
// ok
    NSNumber *value = @(1 << 31); 

// gives compiler error, so max NSNumber is 32-bit uint?
    NSNumber *value = @(1 << 32);
```

Comment: The answers already answer the actual question, so I'll explain the error. The `1` in `1 << 32` is an int, and the compiler uses that when it performs the shift. Since an int is 32 bits, you cannot shift it 32 positions. If you used `@(1ULL << 32)`, it would work, because `1ULL` has a type of unsigned long long.

Comment: Why would this question be voted down? Down vote trolling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSNumber is actually a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html), meaning that when you create an instance you may be getting any of a variety of concrete subclasses, each capable of storing a different kind of numeric type. The actual types available, and their sizes, may be machine-dependent.

Looking at the [NSNumber documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) shows you the different kinds of numbers you can store: the two largest integer options would be [`+numberWithLongLong:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithLongLong%3a) (or `+numberWithUnsignedLongLong:`), which stores a `long long`, and [`+numberWithInteger:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithInteger%3a) (or `+numberWithUnsignedInteger:`), which stores an [NSInteger](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSInteger). The maximum NSNumber values are therefore limited by these types.

The Foundation documentation states:

> When building 32-bit applications, NSInteger is a 32-bit integer. A 64-bit application treats NSInteger as a 64-bit integer.

The compiler is smart and will create an NSNumber of the same type as your numeric literal. As mentioned in the comments above, you can use `@(1ULL << 32)` if your machine has an `unsigned long long` type with more than 32 bits.

Furthermore, NSNumber is toll-free bridged to CFNumber, meaning you can try out functions like [`CFNumberGetByteSize()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNumberGetByteSize) for yourself — and have a look at the [Number Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001209-CH2g-C007966) section of the CFNumber documentation. You'll see these are basically the same as the NSNumber options.

Additionally, the NSDecimalNumber class, a subclass of NSNumber, provides the [`+maximumDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/maximumDecimalNumber) method which you can use to find the maximum value that can be stored in an NSDecimalNumber. NSDecimalNumber, and the floating-point types, may be able to store bigger numbers than the integer types, though with decreasing precision.

Comment: What about `NSNumber *value = @(pow(2, 128));`?

Comment: @Sebastian Since `pow` returns a `double`, the compiler will use `+numberWithDouble:` (or something equivalent to this).

Comment: The largest integer that you could store then, would be using an unsigned long long, which is 64 bit. (18,446,744,073,709,551,615).  NSDecimalNumber is technically a different class, and therefore has a different max number.

Comment: Thanks, all. I updated my answer to address the maximum values of different types.

Comment: @lnafziger Your comment should be the accepted answer.